# Proxy outgoing traffic of Kubernetes cluster through a static IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to build a service that needs to be connected to a socket over the internet without downtime. The service will be reading and publishing info to a message queue, messages should be published only once and in the order received.

For this reason I thought of deploying it into Kubernetes where I can automatically have multiple replicas in case one process fails, i.e. just one process (pod) should be running *all* time, not multiple pods publishing the same messages to the queue.

These requests need to be routed through a proxy with a static IP, otherwise I cannot connect to the socket. I understand this may not be a standard use case as a *reverse proxy* as it is normally use with load balancers such as Nginx.

How is it possible to build this kind of *forward proxy* in Kubernetes?

I will be deploying this on `Google Container Engine`.

Comment: Does incoming traffic also go through the same static IP?

Comment: Please note that Google ks8 offering is called GKE: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/ . GCE provides virtual machines not containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're happy to use Terraform, you can use this:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway

However, there's one caveat and that is it may inbound traffic to other clusters in that same region/zone.

Answer (score 0):

Is the LoadBalancer that you need?

[kubernetes create external loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/),you can see this doc.

Comment: The load balancer routes *incoming* traffic, not outgoing requests.